# what if I delete information_schema database from mySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm curious to know, "**what if I delete information_schema database from mySQL?**"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing. It is a bunch of views, not a real tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html

So you cannot use data modification queries on it.

Comment: Cos, I want to delete this information_schema and create new database due to my hosting allows me to create only two databases.

Comment: @ppshein, it should not count to your database limit because there is only one information_schema database per server and it has no owner.